# Prove that Excel VBA Scripting.Dictionary does not preserve order of item insertion

Tags: arrays, excel, dictionary, vba

I'm trying to decide whether to use Excel VBA Collection or Dictionary for my project. For several reasons, I lean toward dictionary, but I keep reading that when using a `For.. Each` loop to retrieve dictionary items or when reading items from the dictionary Items() array, the order of retrieval may not be the order in which items were added. This would be a serious problem for my application, so I have tried many test cases trying to prove this order mismatch actually occurs. So far, I have not been able to create a scenario where this happens, including adding and removing items in random order.

Can anyone provide an example that proves the retrieval order does not match the order of insertion for the Excel VBA Scripting.Dictionary?

Comment: Where are you reading that? I would think with the inordinate number of posts online about how to sort a dictionary or collection, that the sort order is maintained, otherwise why bother sorting it. It also seems unreasonable that the order would be changed by some mysterious activity happening on the dictionary object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not doing any sorting of items. I simply want to know that if I add items 1, 2, 3, 4 (in that order), then read the items in a For.. Each loop, I don't get 1, 4, 3, 2.

Comment: That's my point though. If so many folks have gone through the trouble of writing dictionary sorting logic then it makes sense that a dictionary order is maintained. Otherwise the sorting logic would be pointless. I'm with you. I don't believe that a dictionary can have it's items reordered arbitrarily.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object is the contractual docs. It makes no mention of order so don't assume one.

Answer (score 10):

No one can provide an example of a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object returning keys/items in a different order than they were added because a Scripting.Dictionary **does not do that**. Never. If you add the following key/item pairs in a progressive order then that is the ways they are returned.

```
key  item
 1    A
 2    B
 3    C
 4    D

'enumerate by key
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dict.Add Key:=1, Item:="A"
dict.Add Key:=2, Item:="B"
dict.Add Key:=3, Item:="C"
dict.Add Key:=4, Item:="D"

Dim k As Variant
For Each k In dict.Keys
    Debug.Print k & " - " & dict.Item(k)
Next k
```

You might be referring to the shorthand 'overwrite' method of adding keys without checking to see it they exist. If you try to [.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h92h863.aspx) a key that exists error 457 is thrown. However, if you simply write [Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/etzd1tzc.aspx) and [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aet97f2.aspx) into the dictionary a new key and item will be created if the key does not exist but if the key exists the key remains the same and the item is overwritten.

```
key  item
 1    A
 2    B
 3    C
 4    D
 2    E

'enumerate by key
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dict.Item(1) = "A"
dict.Item(2) = "B"
dict.Item(3) = "C"
dict.Item(4) = "D"
dict.Item(2) = "E"     'the second entry's item is overwritten

Dim k As Variant
For Each k In dict.Keys
    Debug.Print k & " - " & dict.Item(k)
Next k
```

The overwrite method is a little faster than checking if a key [.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251562.aspx) but the behavior should be understood. I've used the overwrite to intentionally retrieve the last item for any key in a list with duplicate keys but that was a special case. Note that the **2** [.Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ex01tte.aspx) is not out of original order; it has merely had its [.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84k9x471.aspx) replaced with the later one.

If you have added the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference library you can use [Early Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx) in your variable declaration. This has the benefit of creating a slightly faster dictionary object and exposing other methods of indexed enumeration.

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

'enumerate by index position (zero-based index)
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    Debug.Print dict.Keys(i) & " - " & dict.Items(i)
Next i

'enumerate as elements of an array
Dim a As Long
For a = LBound(dict.Keys) To UBound(dict.Keys)
    Debug.Print dict.Keys(a) & " - " & dict.Items(a)
Next a
```

fwiw, I've found this indexed enumeration unreliable when the dictionary's [.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9h9579.aspx) exceeds a signed integer (32,767).

Finally, key/item pairs can be removed one at a time or all at once.

```
dict.Remove 2                              'remove by key

dict.Remove dict.Keys(0)                   'remove first key/item by index position
dict.Remove dict.Keys(UBound(dict.Keys))   'remove last key/item by index position

dict.RemoveAll                             'remove all
```

Comment: Thanks for your info - I'm curious what you mean by the "indexed enumeration unreliable when the dictionary's .Count exceeds a signed integer (32,767)"?

Comment: I was putting together a rewrite of dictionary documentation and discovered 'unreliable results' with a large number of dictionary keys. Until I complete testing under a wider number of conditions, I cannot pinpoint the problem so I used the term 'unreliable'.

Comment: Can you provide any case that you found unreliable?

Comment: Well, you could test this yourself by seeding a large number of rows and building a dictionary of keys and items from that then regurgitating them back to the same worksheet and comparing them. As far as my own experience goes, until I can reproduce empirical trials that show bad results in several versions of Excel (in both 32-bit and 64-bit) I will simply use the term 'unreliable'. To state unevivocaly that something does not work with a smaller test bench would be 'unresponsible'. My original rogue results could have been nothing more than a corrupt environment.

Comment: I've already done what you suggested (up to 1M items) with no bad results.

Comment: You probably know this, but all items can be returned into an array by using Array()=dict.items. Same for keys. Using For Each k In dict.Items causes the items array to be generated only one, then iterated over by the For..Each statement. This is very fast. I have noticed that using a

Comment: ... and all keys or items can be used in a [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) like `.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=dict.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues`. Yes a dictionary is a powerful tool.

Comment: Sorry - did not finish comment above. You probably know this, but all items can be returned into an array by using Array()=dict.items. Same for keys. Using For Each k In dict.Items causes the items array to be generated only one, then iterated over by the For..Each statement. This is very fast. I have noticed that referencing an item or key by index is very slow in a loop because each time dic.Items(a) or dic.Keys(a) appears, the whole array is extracted again just to get the one item or key.

Comment: @JohnM Is the direct lookup faster than accessing the key or item by index? e.g. `dict(key)` vs `dict.Items(i)`